# How to reduce the size of a MediaWiki 'text' table

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

I administer a small MediaWiki wiki that has recently been subject to quite a lot of spam. I've deleted all of the spam accounts and pages and, thanks to the help provided at [How to permanently delete a page from a MediaWiki wiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870930/how-to-permanently-delete-a-page-from-a-mediawiki-wiki/), I've been able to clear out the 'archive' table in the wiki's database so that it's not full of all of the spam pages that I've deleted.

The database is still huge, though, relative to the actual size of the wiki. The 'text' table is running in at 2.7GB, and the 'searchindex' table is a sizeable 302.9MB. What's the best way to go about reducing the size of these tables, particularly the 'text' table? I'd be open to the idea of exporting all of the public-facing parts of the wiki and importing them into a clean install, if this is necessary.

Comment: Not knowing MediaWiki, my first idea would be to identify why the database is so huge in the first place. At least if you're sure it shouldn't be that big...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been trying to do: it's [the 'text' table](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Text_table) that is providing most of the bloat, and no, it shouldn't be that large. I've done everything I can to work out what's going on, so I've posted here :)

Comment: what is the schema of that table ? is there any field allowing a large amount of data ? if yes, the cause is probably in that (those) fields. If no, the the answer can only be in the number of records. Sorry not to give a more accurate answer, but trying to help :-)

Comment: You're entirely right, of course - I think the problem may be in how (or whether) MW deletes data from the database once pages are deleted from the (public-facing part of) the wiki: I've deleted loads of stuff from the wiki, but this hasn't removed anything from the 'text' table. I'm not sure how MW does these things, but if I did know I think I'd be able to solve this :)

Comment: This is common use not to delete records physically but logically, using a flag field (true/false) or even a field with suppression date (the record being considered active is this field is null). How many records do you have ? Would such extension help ? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DeletePagePermanently once again sorry I don't even know what mediawiki is :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently delete a page from a Mediawiki wiki?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870930/how-to-permanently-delete-a-page-from-a-mediawiki-wiki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this (practically, at least) by optimizing the offending table. This reduced its size to between 200 and 300 MB. This still seems large, considering the amount of data present in the wiki, but at least it's manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Just run [`php maintenance/deleteArchivedRevisions.php --delete`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:DeleteArchivedRevisions.php).